# How to hide Authorization code in header?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, authorization, amazon-cognito

Am using AWS Cognito(authorization code grant + openid) for user authentication and callback URL will be S3 static Angular page. After authentication i receive Authorization code(code=964****) in my URL which i will further get and send to backend for retrieving tokens from Cognito. My question is how can i restrict the visibility of Authorization code getting received on my URL. Anyways to restrict it.?

[image]

Comment: Why does it matter?  You still need to do something else to turn the code into actual user information and that will require other credentials to do that.